# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable (pytorch- finetuning model resnet 50 to build pipeline face-recognition)

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

I'm trying to builde pipeline face recognition that uses pytorch.I suppose to build retina-face with arcface . But the upgrade step is causing the error. I don't no why it not run.
Help me please!
Why am I getting this error? I'm confused.

What do you need to know to answer my question?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.functional as F
from torchvision import models, transforms
from torchvision import transforms as T
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets,models, transforms
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, SubsetRandomSampler, DataLoader
import os
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
import copy
from collections import namedtuple, Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler
import time
from torchvision.io import read_image
import os
from typing import Any, Callable, List, Optional, Tuple
from PIL import Image
from torchvision.datasets.utils import check_integrity, download_and_extract_archive, download_url, verify_str_arg
from torchvision.datasets.vision import VisionDataset

class LFWDataset(datasets.ImageFolder):
    def __init__(self, dir, pairs_path, transform=None):

        super(LFWDataset, self).__init__(dir, transform)

        self.pairs_path = pairs_path

        # LFW dir contains 2 folders: faces and lists
        self.validation_images = self.get_lfw_paths(dir)

    def read_lfw_pairs(self, pairs_filename):
        pairs = []
        with open(pairs_filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
                pair = line.strip().split()
                pairs.append(pair)

        return np.array(pairs, dtype=object)

    def get_lfw_paths(self, lfw_dir):
        pairs = self.read_lfw_pairs(self.pairs_path)

        nrof_skipped_pairs = 0
        path_list = []
        issame_list = []
        for pair in pairs:
            if len(pair) == 3:
                path0 = self.add_extension(os.path.join(lfw_dir, pair[0], pair[0] + '_' + '%04d' % int(pair[1])))
                path1 = self.add_extension(os.path.join(lfw_dir, pair[0], pair[0] + '_' + '%04d' % int(pair[2])))
                issame = True
            elif len(pair) == 4:
                path0 = self.add_extension(os.path.join(lfw_dir, pair[0], pair[0] + '_' + '%04d' % int(pair[1])))
                path1 = self.add_extension(os.path.join(lfw_dir, pair[2], pair[2] + '_' + '%04d' % int(pair[3])))
                issame = False
            if os.path.exists(path0) and os.path.exists(path1):  # Only add the pair if both paths exist
                path_list.append((path0, path1, issame))
                issame_list.append(issame)
            else:
                nrof_skipped_pairs += 1
        if nrof_skipped_pairs > 0:
            print('Skipped %d image pairs' % nrof_skipped_pairs)

        return path_list

    def add_extension(self, path):
        if os.path.exists(path + '.jpg'):
            return path + '.jpg'
        elif os.path.exists(path + '.png'):
            return path + '.png'
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('No file "%s" with extension png or jpg.' % path)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """
        Args:
            index: Index of the triplet or the matches - not of a single image
        Returns:
        """

        def transform(img_path):
            img = self.loader(img_path)
            return self.transform(img)

        (path_1, path_2, issame) = self.validation_images[index]
        img1, img2 = transform(path_1), transform(path_2)
        return img1, img2, issame

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.validation_images)

training_data = LFWDataset('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/FaceRecognition/LFW/lfw_funneled',"/content/gdrive/MyDrive/FaceRecognition/LFW/pairsDevTrain.txt")
test_data = LFWDataset('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/FaceRecognition/LFW/lfw_funneled','/content/gdrive/MyDrive/FaceRecognition/LFW/pairsDevTest.txt')

train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

def Deconv(n_input, n_output, k_size=4, stride=2, padding=1):
    Tconv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(
        n_input, n_output,
        kernel_size=k_size,
        stride=stride, padding=padding,
        bias=False)
    block = [
        Tconv,
        nn.BatchNorm2d(n_output),
        nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
    ]
    return nn.Sequential(*block)
        

def Conv(n_input, n_output, k_size=4, stride=2, padding=0, bn=False, dropout=0):
    conv = nn.Conv2d(
        n_input, n_output,
        kernel_size=k_size,
        stride=stride,
        padding=padding, bias=False)
    block = [
        conv,
        nn.BatchNorm2d(n_output),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Dropout(dropout)
    ]
    return nn.Sequential(*block)


class Unet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, resnet):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = resnet.conv1
        self.bn1 = resnet.bn1
        self.relu = resnet.relu
        self.maxpool = resnet.maxpool
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        
        # get some layer from resnet to make skip connection
        self.layer1 = resnet.layer1
        self.layer2 = resnet.layer2
        self.layer3 = resnet.layer3
        self.layer4 = resnet.layer4
        
        # convolution layer, use to reduce the number of channel => reduce weight number
        self.conv_5 = Conv(2048, 512, 1, 1, 0)
        self.conv_4 = Conv(1536, 512, 1, 1, 0)
        self.conv_3 = Conv(768, 256, 1, 1, 0)
        self.conv_2 = Conv(384, 128, 1, 1, 0)
        self.conv_1 = Conv(128, 64, 1, 1, 0)
        self.conv_0 = Conv(32, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        
        # deconvolution layer
        self.deconv4 = Deconv(512, 512, 4, 2, 1)
        self.deconv3 = Deconv(512, 256, 4, 2, 1)
        self.deconv2 = Deconv(256, 128, 4, 2, 1)
        self.deconv1 = Deconv(128, 64, 4, 2, 1)
        self.deconv0 = Deconv(64, 32, 4, 2, 1)
        
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        skip_1 = x
        
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = self.layer1(x)
        skip_2 = x

        x = self.layer2(x)
        skip_3 = x
        x = self.layer3(x)
        skip_4 = x
        
        x5 = self.layer4(x)
        x5 = self.conv_5(x5)
        
        x4 = self.deconv4(x5)
        x4 = torch.cat([x4, skip_4], dim=1)
        x4 = self.conv_4(x4)
        
        x3 = self.deconv3(x4)
        x3 = torch.cat([x3, skip_3], dim=1)
        x3 = self.conv_3(x3)
        
        x2 = self.deconv2(x3)
        x2 = torch.cat([x2, skip_2], dim=1)
        x2 = self.conv_2(x2)
        
        x1 = self.deconv1(x2)
        x1 = torch.cat([x1, skip_1], dim=1)
        x1 = self.conv_1(x1)
        
        x0 = self.deconv0(x1)
        x0 = self.conv_0(x0)
        
        x0 = self.sigmoid(x0)
        return x0
        
device = torch.device("cuda")
resnet50 = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

model = Unet(resnet50)
model.to(device)

## Freeze resnet50's layers in Unet
for i, child in enumerate(model.children()):
    if i <= 7:
        for param in child.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False


train_params = [param for param in model.parameters() if param.requires_grad]
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(train_params, lr=0.001, betas=(0.9, 0.99))

epochs = 5
model.train()
saved_dir = "model"
os.makedirs(saved_dir, exist_ok=True)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss(reduce="mean")

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for img, issame in tqdm(train_dataloader):
        img_gpu = img.to(device)
        outputs = model(img_gpu)
        issame = issame.to(device)
        loss = loss_function(outputs, issame)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

and this is error :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/_reduction.py:42: UserWarning: size_average and reduce args will be deprecated, please use reduction='mean' instead.
  warnings.warn(warning.format(ret))
  0%|          | 0/35 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-68b23124b0a0> in <module>()
      9 
     10 for epoch in range(epochs):
---> 11     for img, issame in tqdm(train_dataloader):
     12         img_gpu = img.to(device)
     13         outputs = model(img_gpu)

6 frames
<ipython-input-4-5d1f05768026> in transform(img_path)
     65 
     66             img = self.loader(img_path)
---> 67             return self.transform(img)
     68 
     69         (path_1, path_2, issame) = self.validation_images[index]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: are you sure that `img_path` is correct in **line 66**

Comment: Hi, when you initialize `training_data = ...` you don't pass a `transform` argument to `LFWDataset` constructor and its default value is `None` as you wrote it. Then it tries to call `None` and fails.

Comment: @FerasAlfrih That's unrelated to the error FYI.

Comment: @Neither if it's not a correct path it would return None since no img to transform, am I wrong about that?

Comment: @FerasAlfrih Error says *'NoneType' object is not callable* which is raised in `__getitem__` of `LFWDataset` implying that image is already somehow loaded and `self.transform`, which is `None` as mentioned above, is causing the issue by trying to be called.

Comment: The issue arises at `self.transform(` part, before even reaching to `img)` part of it.

Comment: @Neither Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Can someone help me fix this here is the link gg colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qF2Si3w5-DpJOkhquG2zOX0KmatmfVw-?usp=sharing

Comment: You are defining function transform() that returns result of calling itself. Python doesn't like endless recurtions... I guess it should return simply 'img'.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You are defining function transform() that returns result of calling itself. Python doesn't like endless recursions... I guess it should return simply 'img':

```
def transform(img_path):
   img = self.loader(img_path)
   return img
```

Comment: I did that but it's has another error :

Comment: ```TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>```

Comment: Please show that in your code: where?